# is_base_of SFINAE toggle on class

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm working on a template toolkit for declarative UI building. I have the templates compiling on Windows as expected but the GCC/clang compilers are taking issue with my SFINAE work.

I'm using Qt as the base, and I'm hoping to include QLayout and QWidget items in the wrapper structure while toggling on/off functions of the wrapper based on the object they represent.

They both derive from QObject which provides a ton of common ground, but I want to include their extended functionality.

On MSVC, the following works exceptionally well

```
// let cls be the input subclass of QWidget or
// QLayout which is passed to the owning wrapper template
template<typename = std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<QWidget, cls>::value == true>>
Wrapper &style() {
    cast()->setStyleSheet(stylesheet);
    return *this;
}
```

However GCC/clang don't agreed. I've tried using something akin to:

```
template<typename Empty = void,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<QWidget, cls>::value, Empty
    >::type
>
Wrapper &style(const QString &stylesheet) {
    cast()->setStyleSheet(stylesheet);
    return *this;
}
```

But still get an error stating that QLayout subclasses don't have a member `setStyleSheet`. And while it doesn't, I was hoping to have the compiler skip over the function entirely as it does in MSVC.

I'm assuming I have a misunderstanding of the SFINAE system and need to either adjust my template declaration, or just suck it up and split the two items and repeat the code.

**EDIT:**

Reproduction of Issue:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oGzsKhrn4

The top bits are just minimal reprs of Qt objects and it represents the same basic structure I'm after, you can mostly ignore them.

The macros are to ease the templating required for each class. If nothing else, I can always break it up and add additional macros to fill in QWidget vs. QLayout functionality, I just liked how clean it was for Windows.

Comment: What is `cls`? How is it related to `style()`?

Comment: Until recently, MSVC didn't properly implement two-phase name lookup. Essentially, it treated templates as macros and parsed them just well enough to find the closing brace; then fully reparsed them at instantiation time. This is non-conforming; a conforming compiler would parse and validate most of the template at the point of definition, and only defer looking up dependent names at the point of instantiation. You are likely relying on this deficiency of MSVC. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve]. As written, it's unclear what `cls`, `cast()` or `stylesheet` are.

Comment: Minimal is a challenge for me, as most of my other attempts to reproduce on a small scale have failed. I did manage to put together something that does bring up the error and updated the question, but it's not quite tiny.

Comment: Ugh, macro abuse. Can you try to come up with a [mre] that does not use macros that make the code hard to understand, and comprehend?

Comment: Fair point - I've unpacked the macros and tried to reduce as much as possible while still including the full picture of what I'm after. That said, I did end up just splitting the macro up to avoid the problem. It's one extra line of code per wrapper class but better than spinning on this any longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the behavior of `style` function body is not dependent on its template parameters and a compiler can check the correctness. I guess this is allowed by the standard in [[temp.res#general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#general-6.4):

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if: 
> ... 
> — a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, 
> ...

However, you can make `QVBoxLayout` a template default parameter as before (instead of `Empty`), but make the body dependent on this parameter too:

```
template<typename QVBoxLayout_ = QVBoxLayout,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<QWidget, QVBoxLayout_>::value, void
    >::type
>
VLayout &style(const QString &stylesheet) {
    QVBoxLayout_::cast()->setStyleSheet(stylesheet); // "shouldn't matter"
    return *this;
}
```

But in this case we have an issue. Some user might accidentally pass this parameter and SFINAE will be broken, so I propose the following fix. Add a parameter pack as a first function template parameter. It will "eat" all accidentally passed parameters, so users won't be able to override the default parameters:

```
template<typename..., typename QVBoxLayout_ = QVBoxLayout...
```

And, of course, you can add an assertion that a user does not try to override these parameters unintentionally. In summary:

```
template<typename... ParameterGuard_, 
    typename QVBoxLayout_ = QVBoxLayout,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<QWidget, QVBoxLayout_>::value, void
    >::type
>
VLayout &style(const QString &stylesheet) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(ParameterGuard_) == 0, 
        "This function template is not intended to accept template parameters");

    QVBoxLayout_::cast()->setStyleSheet(stylesheet); // "shouldn't matter"
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I see! With one small adjustment (Using `VLayout` instead of `QVBoxLayout` as the owner of `::cast()` worked like a charm. So I needed an additional `typename VLayout_ = VLayout` in the template, then call cast with that.